# Display alternate content when Flash is not installed with jquery.swfobject

Tags: jquery, html, flash, swfobject

How can I display alternate HTML with the jquery.swfobject plugin for browsers without Flash? I'm unable to find any documentation or examples showing how to do this.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="jquery.1.4.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="jquery.swfobject.1-0-9.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#contentflash").flash({
                swf: "myswf.swf",               
                width: "100%",
                height: "100%",
                params: {
                    wmode: "opaque"
                }
            });

        });             
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="contentflash"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try placing some content in the

```
<div id="contentflash"></div>
```

Like

```
<div id="contentflash">No flash here man !</div>
```

This

```
$("#contentflash").flash
```

replaces the id #contentflash being targeted.

Here is an [example](http://jquery.lukelutman.com/plugins/flash/example-flashblock.html) for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

See [this example](http://jquery.lukelutman.com/plugins/flash/example-basic.html). The content of the box is only replaced if flash is enabled. This doesn't remove the "go install flash" message, though.