# using a .swf virtual tour file on a html5 website

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I have developed a website using html5/bootstrap and one of the pages has a sample swf virtual tour. it's all ready to deploy apart from this final issue:

I have a .swf virtual tour that works fine on Google chrome etc. but obviously doesn't work on mobile devices because it is a flash based file.

What I need is a way to view this file maybe in an iframe etc. that will work on all mobile devices.

Any suggestions would be a real help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your best option is to use a JS plugin like `jQuery SWFObject`, and fall back to a message/alternate image if Flash is not installed on the device. Otherwise, an iFrame won't help you (doesn't change the fact that you need flash installed).

> SWFObject Example: http://jquery.thewikies.com/swfobject/
>
> Source:
>   [Display alternate content when Flash is not installed with jquery.swfobject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962286/display-alternate-content-when-flash-is-not-installed-with-jquery-swfobject)

Answer (score 2):

Convert your SWF to HTML5 with [Google Swiffy](https://developers.google.com/swiffy/?hl=en):

> A simple Flash to HTML5 converter that helps make SWF files available
>   to a larger audience.